# Pre-loading Model Schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a list of schema below with their associations.

**user**

- `has_one avatar`
- `has_many posts`
- `has_many comments`

**avatar**

- `belongs_to user`

**post**

- `belongs_to user`
- `has_many comments`

**comment**

- `belongs_to user`
- `belongs_to post`

My Problem is I'm trying to join my **post** -> **comment** -> **user** -> **avatar** in a query.

```
def get_post_comments!(id) do
query =
  from(
    p in Post,
    where: p.id == ^id,
    select: p,
    join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
    join: l in assoc(c, :user),
    join: d in assoc(l, :avatar),
    preload: [comments: {c, user: l, avatar: d}]
  )

IO.inspect(Repo.one!(query))end
```

I'm getting an error of

> (Ecto.QueryError) field `BazaarApp.Market.Comment.avatar` in preload is not an association in query:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it clumsy mistake forgot to add brackets.

**From**

```
preload: [comments: {c, user: l, avatar: d}]
```

**To**

```
preload: [comments: {c, [user: {l, avatar: d}] }]
```